# Meaning of data in release certificate for Android

Tags: android

When you create a new keystore / certificate for use with a production release of an Android APK, you can fill out lots of stuff like city, state, country code etc. 
When you have a look at the certificate with

```
jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose some_application.apk
```

those aren't even visible.

Do those data have any meaning, for example a legal one? Or are they just for organizational purpose (say you have to manage hundreds of keystores / certificates)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are for organizational purpose. First section (alias, password, validity...) is the most important. Recommended is filling a `First and Last name` input, other aren't required and important for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The validity in years in pretty important to apps uploaded to the play store.